# how can i solve segmentation error in terminal message?

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

I wrote a simple program to take names and numbers from the user and store it in an array, then compare between each cell until it reach the maximum grade then it displays it. The problem is that when it run it shows a message (segmentation fault (Core dump)). I really don't know what my mistake is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", & n);
    char name[n];
    float score[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter the name of Student: ");
        scanf("%s", & name[i]);
        printf("\nEnter the score:  ");
        scanf("%f", & score[i]);
    }
    float max;
    int index;
    max = score[0];
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (max < score[i]) {
            max = score[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    printf("\nHighest mark scored is %f by student %s", name[index], score[index]);
}
```

Comment: char only stores one character.  You need to use strings.  Read up on that

Comment: regardinng: `printf("\nHighest mark scored is %f by student %s", name[index], score[index]);`  this fails to compile!  The parameters 'score' and 'name' must be in the same order as the output conversion operators '%f' and '%s' in the format string

Comment: for robustness, regarding: `scanf("%s", & name[i]);`  the input conversion '%s' needs a MAX WIDTH modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input array.  1 less because this conversion operator always appends a NUL byte to the end of the input

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
1- you use user input to define the size of an array (wrong)
-- array in c has static size so you must define it's size before the code reach the compiling stage(use dynamic memory allocation instead)
2- scanf("%s", & name[I]); you want  to save array of char and save the address at the name variable but name it self not a pointer to save address it's just of char type  (wrong)
-- you need pointer to save the address of every name so it's array of pointer and a pointer to allocate the address of the array to it so it's  a pointer to poiner and define max size of word if you define size the user input exceed it will produce an error
3- finally you exchanged the %f,%s in printf 





    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define SIZE_OF_WORD 10

    int main() {
        int n;
    printf("Enter the number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", & n);
    char **name=(char**)malloc((sizeof(char*)*n));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        name[i]=(char*)malloc((sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_WORD));
    }
    float *score=(float*)malloc((sizeof(float)*n));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter the name of Student: ");
        scanf("%s", name[i]);
        printf("\nEnter the score:  ");
        scanf("%f", & score[i]);
    }
    float max;
    int index;
    max = score[0];
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (max < score[i]) {
            max = score[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    printf("\nHighest mark scored is %s by student %.0f\n", name[index],score[index]);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `char **name=(char**)malloc((sizeof(char)*n));` be allocating enough space for `n` pointers and not chars? Your first statement is incorrect. Variable length arrays are valid in C99.

Comment: regarding: `float *score=(float*)malloc((sizeof(float)*n));`  in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone

Comment: regarding:  `printf("\nHighest mark scored is %s by student %.0f\n", name[index],score[index]);`  the highest 'score' is a 'float' not a string.  Similar considerations for the student name.  So the parameters 2 and 3 are reversed

Comment: regarding: `char **name=(char**)malloc((sizeof(char)*n));` the `sizeof(char)`  should be `sizeof( char *)`